# selection sort algorithm produces out of order results

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write a program to demonstrate the selection sort algorithm in an array pointer but the result is really out of whack.

I have run it on multiple compilers, but it does not seem to change the result.

```cpp
void SelectionSort(int *arr[], int size)
{
    int start, minI;
    int *MinEl;
    for (start = 0; start < (size - 1); start++)
    {
        minI = start;
        MinEl = arr[start];
        for (int i = start + 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (*(arr[i]) < *MinEl);
            {
                MinEl = arr[i];
                minI = i;
            }
        }

        arr[minI] = arr[start];
        arr[start] = MinEl;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be a sorted array and the original, but the sorted array seems to be sorted incorrectly.

Comment: This needs a [mcve]. This *looks* like you're sorting a *table* of rows of `int`, based on the value in the first column only. Update your question to include required source to compile, and setup to test, so we can achieve the same results you're getting. That said, your swap looks... off.

Comment: *I have ran it on multiple compilers but it does not seem to change the result* -- It is a bug in your code.  No need to try this on multiple compilers.

Comment: On the other hand, when there are no visible bugs, you DO want to run the program through multiple compilers. One might spot or expose something the others don't.

Comment: You should include sample input and the output produced for that input. (A good idea would be to hardcode the input in your [mcve], once you have that.) Sometimes what looks random to you will have a pattern recognizable to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
        if (*(arr[i]) < *MinEl);
```

The `;` at the end makes that code worthless. Probably you get some warning.

The next block gets executed unconditionally.

Anyway, using `int *arr[]` seems odd to me, you usually use `int arr[]`.

Working version corrected: https://ideone.com/2wZXVs

Comment: Thank you very much sir!